# Eclipse Scout Neon mock backend service

Tags: eclipse-scout

In our project I have modules scout.client, scout.server, scout.shared and backend.

Backend has no dependencies to scout.server and scout.shared, but scout.server has dependencies to backend.

[image]

Inside backend project I have all business logic and calling all outside services.

My problem is when I try to test scout services that use some service from backend.

Because scout provide some great tool for mocking beans, we defined our service inside backend as beans as :

```
 BEANS.getBeanManager().registerClass(CarService.class);
 BEANS.getBeanManager().registerClass(PartnerService.class);
```

Both, CarService.class and PartnerService.class are in backend.

When I try to write some tests and I add @BeanMock to service in test

```
@BeanMock
private IPartnerService partnerService;
```

I get mock, but then every return every function is null, even if I write

```
doReturn(PartnerBuilder.standardPartnerListWithOneElement()).when(this.partnerService)
    .getPartners(any(Set.class));
```

If I debug in my test, before this test is called with debugger I can get :

```
  partnerService.getPartners(...) -> return a list of person
```

what is right, but when class that is tested calles this service it return null.

I understand that this could be due to missing annotation on interface `@ApplicationScoped`. Without this there is no guarantee that only one `bean` is created, and `when` statement react on another copy of that bean...?

I could not add annotation on interface because backend has no dependencies to scout modules.

How could I handle this kind of cases?

---

Tested class is :

```
 public class UtilityPartner {

  /**
   * Method return service bean for getting partners by ids.
   *
   * @return
   */
   private static IPartnerService getPartnerService() {

    return BEANS.get(IPartnerService.class);
   }

  public static String getPartnerName(final Long partnerId) {

    if (partnerId == null) {
      return "";
    }

    final List<Partner> partners =
        (List<Partner>) getPartnerService().getPartners(Sets.newHashSet(partnerId));
    if (partners == null || partners.isEmpty()) {
      return "";
    }
    final Partner partner = partners.get(0);
    return LookupUtil.createLookupDescription(partner.getId(), partner.getName());
  }

}
```

test class is :

```
 @RunWith(ServerTestRunner.class)
 @RunWithSubject("anonymous")
 @RunWithServerSession(ServerSession.class)
 public class TestUtilityPartner {

    @BeanMock
    private IPartnerService partnerService;

     @Before
     public void init() {
         doReturn(PartnerBuilder.standardPartnerListWithOneElement()).when(this.partnerService).getPartners(any(Set.class));

     }

     @Test
     public void getPartnerName() {

        final String name = UtilityPartner.getPartnerName(10L);
        Assert.assertEquals("My name", name); // NAME IS ""
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should register your mock instance in the Bean manager (See [bean registration](http://eclipsescout.github.io/5.2/latest/book_scout_architecture/scout_architecture/scout_architecture.html#bean-registration) in the Scout Architecture Document). You should use a small order ([-10 000 is recommended for tests](http://eclipsescout.github.io/5.2/latest/book_scout_architecture/scout_architecture/scout_architecture.html#order)), in order for your mock to win over the productive registration. The best approach is to use the `TestingUtility` class to register/unregister your mock. Do not forget to call the `unregisterBean()` method (in the method annotated with `@After`):

```
import java.util.Collections;

import org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.BeanMetaData;
import org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.IBean;
import org.eclipse.scout.rt.testing.shared.TestingUtility;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class TestUtilityPartner {

    private IBean<?> beanRegistration;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        partnerService = Mockito.mock(IPartnerService.class);

        // Register the mock using the Bean meta information:
        BeanMetaData beanData = new BeanMetaData(IPartnerService.class)
           .withInitialInstance(partnerService)
           .withApplicationScoped(true);
        this.beanRegistration = TestingUtility.registerBean(beanData);


       // Mockito behavior:
       Mockito.doReturn(Collections.singletonList(new Partner(34L, "John Smith")))
           .when(partnerService).getPartners(Mockito.any(Set.class));
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        // Unregister the mocked services:
        TestingUtility.unregisterBean(this.beanRegistration);
    }

    @Test
    public void getPartnerName() {
        String name = UtilityPartner.getPartnerName(10L);
        Assert.assertEquals("10 - John Smith", name);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what `@BeanMock` (`org.eclipse.scout.rt.testing.platform.mock.BeanMock`) is doing, but according to [Judith Gull's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36429684/91497) it will not work:

> Using `@BeanMock` does not help here, because you are not using an application scoped service:
>
> In the init method you are changing the local field partnerService. However, in your test you call UtilityPartner.getPartnerService, which is creating a new instance (with `BEANS.get(IPartnerService.class)`).
>
> `@BeanMock` is more useful for convenience for mocking application scoped beans.

Comment: Wow this work! I have additional question : would it be better that I registrate BEAN as you posted here when I registrate my bean (not in test but in PlatformListener)?

Comment: I can not answer this in the comment. Moving your second question to an other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164077/scout-bean-manager-registerclass-or-registerbean

Comment: I have updated the example to use `TestingUtility`. You should update your code.

Answer (score 2):

Using `@BeanMock` does not help here, because you are not using an application scoped service:

In the init method you are changing the local field partnerService. However, in your test you call UtilityPartner.getPartnerService, which is creating a new instance (with `BEANS.get(IPartnerService.class)`).

`@BeanMock` is more useful for convenience for mocking application scoped beans.

You can always register your beans manually [as shown by Jmini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36147550/91497). Please do not forget to unregister the bean again after the test!

We recommend using `org.eclipse.scout.rt.testing.shared.TestingUtility.registerBean(BeanMetaData)`, which is automatically adding a testing order and removing `@TunnelToServer` annotations.