# Scout Bean Manager: registerClass(..) or registerBean(..)

Tags: eclipse-scout

In our project we have following modules `scout.client`, `scout.server`, `scout.shared` and `backend`.

`backend` has no dependencies to `scout.server` and `scout.shared`, but `scout.server` has dependencies to `backend`.

[image: screenshot]

Inside the `backend` project we have all business logic and calling all outside services.

We use the Scout Bean Manager to manage the instances of the Backend-Services in our `scout.server`:

```
BEANS.getBeanManager().registerClass(CarService.class);
BEANS.getBeanManager().registerClass(PartnerService.class);
```

Both, `CarService.class` and `PartnerService.class` are in the `backend`.

Is this registration correct? Or should I register the classes using the `registerBean(..)` method instead of `registerClass(..)`?

---

Question derived from an [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132254/eclipse-scout-neon-mock-backend-service/36147550?noredirect=1#comment59944096_36147550) asked by [@marko-zadravec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2791346/marko-zadravec)

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the `registerClass(..)` JavaDoc, if you do:

```
public class RegisterBeansListener implements IPlatformListener {
  @Override
  public void stateChanged(PlatformEvent event) {
    if (event.getState() == IPlatform.State.BeanManagerPrepared) {
      // register the class directly:
      BEANS.getBeanManager().registerClass(BeanSingletonClass.class);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the same as:

```
public class RegisterBeansListener implements IPlatformListener {
  @Override
  public void stateChanged(PlatformEvent event) {
    if (event.getState() == IPlatform.State.BeanManagerPrepared) {
      // register with meta information
      BeanMetaData beanData = new BeanMetaData(PartnerService.class);
      BEANS.getBeanManager().registerBean(beanData);
    }
  }
}
```

Meaning that you will get a new instance of the `PartnerService` each time you call `BEANS.get(IPartnerService.class)`. (see [Bean Scopes](http://eclipsescout.github.io/6.0/latest/book_scout_architecture/scout_architecture/scout_architecture.html#bean-scopes) in the Scout Docs).

If you want your bean to have only one instance for your entire application you should register it like that:

```
public class RegisterBeansListener implements IPlatformListener {
  @Override
  public void stateChanged(PlatformEvent event) {
    if (event.getState() == IPlatform.State.BeanManagerPrepared) {
      // register with meta information
      BeanMetaData beanData = new BeanMetaData(PartnerService.class)
          .withApplicationScoped(true);
      BEANS.getBeanManager().registerBean(beanData);
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend setting [a specific Order like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36147550) only for test purpose.